# Собрать проект с помощью maven

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven, jar

Хочу собрать исполняемый jar файлик который можно запустить из консоли: но беда вот в чем - плагин assembly и сборка проекта через intellijidea при запуске jar говорят ClassNotFoundException. В манифесте все, вроде как, указано было супер. Подскажите, как можно собрать проект со всеми зависимостями?

мой pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>farm-dog</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/ch.qos.logback/logback-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.7.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>30.0-jre</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/hamcrest-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.projectlombok/lombok -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.12</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


</project>
```

Так же я попробовала след плагин и собрать проект с помощью команды mvn package:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.example.farm.Runner</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Структура:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте сообщение об ошибки, чтобы было понятно, какой класс не находит и стектрейс, чтоб было ясно кто и в какой момент не находит.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574594/how-can-i-create-an-executable-jar-with-dependencies-using-maven

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте этот плагин:

```
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.example.farm.Runner</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: быыло) я написала выше что юзала assembly

Comment: а вы что нибудь считываете или записываете в своей проге (используете InputStream/OutputStream)?

Comment: неа, максимум system out println и логи

Comment: а какой именно класс не может найти?

Comment: главный) хотя в манифесте он прописан. В моем случае это com.exaple.farm.Runner

Comment: можете показать скрин структуры вашего проекта (папок)

Comment: прикрепила к вопросу

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117305/discussion-between-am233dmg-and-anastasiya).